# Check if image is grayscale without a for loop

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing

I'm trying replace the following code that checks if the image is grayscale by analyzing the actual image content itself (not just the total number of channels) to code that uses `np.any()` or something that allows me to remove the for-loops:

```
from scipy.misc import imread
import numpy as np

def check_grayscale(image):
    image = imread('input.jpg').astype(np.float64)
    w = image.shape[0]
    h = image.shape[1]
    for i in range(w):
        for j in range(h):
            r, g, b = image[i][j]
            if r != g != b:
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: Why have you removed your `import` statements? Your code cannot run without them,  nor can anyone experiment with it. Which module does `imread()` come from please?

Comment: scipy.misc (version 1.1.0)

Comment: You are essentially testing that the red channel equals the green channel `np.equal(image[...,0], image[...,1]` and likewise green channel equals blue `np.equal(image[...,1], image[...,2])` But if using floats, you should probably use `np.allclose()`

Comment: Does your function work?

Comment: Yes, it works by using this line: np.allclose(np.equal(image[:,:,0], image[:,:,1]), np.equal(image[:,:,1], image[:,:,2]))

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you're checking to see if the image is grayscale.  Grayscale images are such that all RGB channels are equal to each other for the entire image.  What you can do is use the first channel and check to see if any pixels aren't equal to any of the other channels by broadcasting:

```
check = ~np.any(np.any(image[...,0][:,:,None] != image, axis=2))
```

Please note that the above assumes `uint8` or integer pixels.  It is highly recommended you do not compare with floating-point comparison such as how you've done in your code when converting to this.  To use the code above, please remove the floating-point conversion. Integer comparison is safer.  We'll first check to see if any pixels in the first channel are not equal to any pixels for all of the other channels in your image.  Once that's done, we wrap another `np.any` call one more time to characterize the entire image.  `check` contains that result - `True` being that your image is grayscale and `False` otherwise. Note the inversion of the final result since we are explicitly checking for any pixels that aren't equal, and when we use `np.any` to reduce it all down to a single answer but we'll have to invert because we were checking for the opposite situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this - it's not as hard as it looks, there are several lines of setup and a few commented out DEBUG lines to show my thinking. The actual code is a one-liner.

It is basically checking that the entire red channel of the image (`im[...,0]`) matches the entire green channel (`im[...,1]`) and likewise red matches blue.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

# Synthesize single channel, grey image of randomness
rangrey = np.random.randint(0,256,(480,640,1), dtype=np.uint8)

# Make RGB equivalent with R=G=B by stacking initial image 3x
ranrgb  = np.dstack((rangrey,rangrey,rangrey))

# DEBUG: Check shape
# print(ranrgb,shape)      # prints (480, 640, 3)

# DEBUG: Check red channel equals green channel throughout image
# DEBUG print(np.equal(ranrgb[...,0],ranrgb[...,1]).all())     # prints True

# DEBUG: Check red channel equals blue channel throughout image
# DEBUG print(np.equal(ranrgb[...,0],ranrgb[...,2]).all())     # prints True

isGrey = np.equal(ranrgb[...,0],ranrgb[...,1]).all() and np.equal(ranrgb[...,1],ranrgb[...,2]).all()
print(isGrey)    # prints True

# Now change one pixel and check
ranrgb[0,0,0] += 1

isGrey = np.equal(ranrgb[...,0],ranrgb[...,1]).all() and np.equal(ranrgb[...,1],ranrgb[...,2]).all()
print(isGrey)    # prints False
```

If your image is `float64` for some unknown reason, you should use `np.allclose()` in place of `np.equal()`.

Note that, because of the `and` in the middle of the test for `isGrey`, the second half of the test can be short-circuited (omitted to save half the time) since, if it is already clear that the red channel does not match the green channel there is no point checking what's going on in the blue channel.